# Django Rest Framework - problem with filtering data

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

in my models i have Book and Author with M2M relationship.

```
models.py

from django.db import models


from django.db import models


class Book(models.Model):
    title          = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    published_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False)
    categories     = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
    average_rating = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    ratings_count  = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    thumbnail      = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)

def authors(self):
    return self.author_set.all()

def __str__(self):
    return f'title: {self.title} \n' \
           f'date of publication: {self.published_date}'


class Author(models.Model):
    name  = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    books = models.ManyToManyField(Book)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

in my serializer i'm getting authors from `def authors` in models.py

```
serializers.py
```

```
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ['name']


class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    authors = AuthorSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = [
            'authors',
            'title',
            'published_date',
            'categories',
            'average_rating',
            'ratings_count',
            'thumbnail'
        ]
```

so in views.py i want to filter books by authors

```
views.py
```

```
class BooksListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Book.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BookSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.OrderingFilter, DjangoFilterBackend)
    filter_fields = ['published_date', 'authors']
    ordering_fields = ['published_date']
```

but it gives me this error

```
'Meta.fields' must not contain non-model field names: authors
```

any idea how can i filter data with authors so i can extract books of given authors.
I would like to have a choice of selecting filters.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You remove the `authors` from the `fields`, and let this be handled by the `AuthorSerializer` in the serializer:

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    authors = AuthorSerializer(source='author_set', many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = [  # ← no authors
            'author_set',
            'title',
            'published_date',
            'categories',
            'average_rating',
            'ratings_count',
            'thumbnail'
        ]
```

Note that you can rename the relation in reverse with the `related_name=…` parameter:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name  = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    books = models.ManyToManyField(Book, related_name='authors')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

in that case, the source is simply `authors`:

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    #                   no source ↓
    authors = AuthorSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = [
            'authors',
            'title',
            'published_date',
            'categories',
            'average_rating',
            'ratings_count',
            'thumbnail'
        ]
```

Comment: it gives me this error:The field 'authors' was declared on serializer BookSerializer, but has not been included in the 'fields' option.

Comment: @dawid: but did you set the `source` to `author_set`?

Comment: Yes i did and i removed def authors from model and removed authors from fields in Bookserializer

Comment: Should i leave this def authors method in models.py?

Comment: @dawid: did you set the `related_name` to `authors`?

Comment: @dawid: then you should add `authors` to the `fields`.

Comment: Could you also tell me if there is a way to make authors present as a list instead of a queryset ?

Comment: @dawid: I'm not really sure what you mean, the `QuerySet` will be serialized as a list normally.

Comment: I mean authors is displaying like this  `"authors": [{ "name": "John Ronald Reuel Tolkien" }]`, and i would like to be like `"authors": [ "John Ronald Reuel Tolkien"]`

Comment: @dawid: yes, you can work with a [**`StringRelatedField`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#stringrelatedfield) instead of a the `AuthorSerializer`.